# Minor alignment issue with "draft saved" and "draft discarded" in the answer section

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, draft

There is a minor alignment issue in the answer section while composing the answer.
When the draft is saved or discarded, the notice is not aligned with the community wiki checkbox.

**When draft saved:**

> [image: Draft saved]

---

**When draft discarded:**

> [image: Draft Discarded]

Comment: Related bug report on ruSO: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5368

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this issue. This has been corrected and is live in production. Draft statuses are again aligned to the left.

Also the community wiki checkbox has been updated so it has more space between it and the answer textarea. This is what it looks like now:

[image: This is what it looks like now.]